# Fout: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/home

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, expression

I tried for a couple of hours now, but so far I can't find anything for the problem.
I'm trying to load pages with jQuery (which is working), but my url looks like this:
http://c-vizion.nl/wim/#!/home (`<li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>`)

This is not working for some reason, firefox says this:
Fout: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/home

I just don't understand why I can't use #! in my url, obviously I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Could someone please help me to fix this?

Best Regards,
Chris Jasperse

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your href should be

```
<li><a href="/wim/#!/home">Home</a></li>
```

so you get the full path.

Comment: When I start my website from:
http://c-vizion.nl/wim/
It works!
But when I start at:
http://c-vizion.nl/wim/home
It won't work...

This all seems really strange for me...
Does someone have an explanation for me?

Comment: /wim/#!/home and /wim/home are two very different paths. In the first example, the browser is asking for the page /wim/ then applying #!/home in the browser, AFTER the page gets returned. In the second case, the browser is asking for /wim/home which looks like an invalid path in your app (no routes? No file?) which is causing the 404. See also http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ for how Google uses #!